# R XML : Error in UseMethod("xmlNamespaceDefinitions")

Tags: xml, r

I'm trying to scrape XML data on R and encountering following error
XML link : http://data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Arecanut(Betelnut_Supari)_2005.xml
Code:

```
library(RCurl);
library(XML)
test <- readHTMLTable(doc="http://data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Arecanut(Betelnut_Supari)_2005.xml")
```

Error:

```
Error in UseMethod("xmlNamespaceDefinitions") : 
  no applicable method for 'xmlNamespaceDefinitions' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

Comment: the link provided for the .xml does not work for me

Comment: It's a big-ish file (3M) and I grabbed it from a UK digital ocean box (so it might be geo-restricted).

Answer (score 1):

The file was not "easy" to get and, since it's >3MB in size, it's best practice to download the file first then process it. Next, you aren't parsing HTML, you're reading an XML SOAP response, so you would not have gotten far with `readHTMLTable` even without the namespace issues. The records you are trying to extract look like:

```
<diffgr:diffgram>
  <NewDataSet>
    <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
      <State>Assam</State>
      <District>Barpeta</District>
      <Market>Howly</Market>
      <Commodity>Arecanut(Betelnut/Supari)</Commodity>
      <Variety>Other</Variety>
      <Arrival_Date>18/06/2005</Arrival_Date>
      <Min_x0020_Price>5000</Min_x0020_Price>
      <Max_x0020_Price>8000</Max_x0020_Price>
      <Modal_x0020_Price>6500</Modal_x0020_Price>
    </Table>
    …
```

Since the `diffgram` node has a namespace (`diffgr`) you need to extract the nodes with said namespace in mind then turn the children nodes into data frame rows. Further explanation is inline with the solution:

```
library(XML)
library(data.table)

# be kind to data providers + have the file in case the Internet is down or they
# move the file and, finally, speed up processing later on by having it local
#
# download.file("http://data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Arecanut(Betelnut_Supari)_2005.xml", 
#                destfile="arecanut_2005.xml")

dat <- xmlTreeParse("arecanut_2005.xml", useInternalNodes=TRUE)

# There are namespaces in the XML file, so we need to extract them
nsDefs <- xmlNamespaces(dat, recursive=TRUE)
ns <- structure(sapply(nsDefs, function(x) x$uri), names = names(nsDefs))

# the "table" nodes use diffgr:diffgram, so we need to make sure we include
# the diffgr namespace which is ns[9]

nodes <- getNodeSet(dat ,"//diffgr:diffgram/NewDataSet/Table", ns[9])

# we then loop through the nodes, converting each set of values to a 
# data frame then using data.table's rbindlist with `fill=TRUE` just in
# case some records have greater or fewer fields.

tmp <- rbindlist(lapply(nodes, function(x) {
   as.data.frame.list(xmlApply(x, xmlValue))
}), fill=TRUE)

str(tmp)

## Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  8127 obs. of  9 variables:
##  $ State            : Factor w/ 9 levels "Assam","Goa",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ District         : Factor w/ 30 levels "Barpeta","Darrang",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ Market           : Factor w/ 50 levels "Howly","Kharupetia",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ Commodity        : Factor w/ 1 level "Arecanut(Betelnut/Supari)": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ Variety          : Factor w/ 26 levels "Other","Supari",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ Arrival_Date     : Factor w/ 323 levels "18/06/2005","19/06/2005",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
##  $ Min_x0020_Price  : Factor w/ 1923 levels "5000","1000",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
##  $ Max_x0020_Price  : Factor w/ 2394 levels "8000","1250",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 ...
##  $ Modal_x0020_Price: Factor w/ 2385 levels "6500","1100",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 ...
##  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

head(tmp)

##     State District Market                 Commodity Variety Arrival_Date Min_x0020_Price Max_x0020_Price Modal_x0020_Price
## 1: Assam  Barpeta  Howly Arecanut(Betelnut/Supari)   Other   18/06/2005            5000            8000              6500
## 2: Assam  Barpeta  Howly Arecanut(Betelnut/Supari)   Other   19/06/2005            5000            8000              6500
## 3: Assam  Barpeta  Howly Arecanut(Betelnut/Supari)   Other   20/06/2005            5000            8000              6500
## 4: Assam  Barpeta  Howly Arecanut(Betelnut/Supari)   Other   21/06/2005            5000            8000              6500
## 5: Assam  Barpeta  Howly Arecanut(Betelnut/Supari)   Other   22/06/2005            5000            8000              6500
## 6: Assam  Barpeta  Howly Arecanut(Betelnut/Supari)   Other   24/06/2005            5000            8000              6500
```

If you're going to continue to work with these types of files, it would be in your best interest to [read up a bit](http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/) on XML processing in R.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am beginner to R and I'll definitely have to start reading about XML processing.